# How to make dropdownlist show a selected value in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, findby

I have an edit page with a Html.DropDownList in it....I cant show the dropdownlist value it always shows up with `Select` instead i want to make the dropdown show an item as selected based on a model value say `Model.Mes_Id`... Any suggestion how it can be done...

```
       <p>
            <label for="MeasurementTypeId">MeasurementType:</label>
         <%= Html.DropDownList("MeasurementType", // what should i give here?)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("MeasurementTypeId", "*") %>
        </p>
```

**EDIT:** It has the list items but i want to show a value selected in the edit view...

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var mesurementTypes = consRepository.FindAllMeasurements();
        ViewData["MeasurementType"] = mesurementTypes;
        var material = consRepository.GetMaterial(id);
        return View("Edit", material);
    }
```

My repository method,

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FindAllMeasurements()
        {
            var mesurements = from mt in db.MeasurementTypes
                              select new SelectListItem
                              {
                                 Value = mt.Id.ToString(),
                                 Text= mt.Name
                              };
            return mesurements;
        }
```

Comment: More detail please. the code you posted <%= Html.DropDownList("MeasurementType", "Select")%> does exactly what it should. Create a <SELECT> tag with one option and its value is "select". What are you trying to accomplish? Note HTML.DropDownList has like 9 overloads.

Comment: @john consider my dropdown list contains 9 items.... `Model.Mes_Id=5` and i want select MeasurementType with value `5` in my edit view 
`http://localhost:1985/Materials/Edit/13`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the selected item when you create the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Personally I would create a specialized viewmodel for the form but going by your code, do something like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    //Put this first
    var material = consRepository.GetMaterial(id);
    //pass in your selected item
    var mesurementTypes = consRepository.FindAllMeasurements(material.MeasurementTypeId);
    ViewData["MeasurementType"] = mesurementTypes;

    return View("Edit", material);
}
```

Then change your repository method to something like:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FindAllMeasurements(int selectedId)
{
     var mesurements = from mt in db.MeasurementTypes
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                         Value = mt.Id.ToString(),
                         Text= mt.Name,
                         Selected = mt.Id == selectedId
                      };

    return mesurements;
}
```

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: @Charlino that worked..... It works for edit but how will this method act for add view where i dont want a selected value...

Comment: If you just pass in 0 none of the values should be selected - assuming that you don't have a MeasurementType with an id of 0! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog entry.

http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/03/27/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-and-selected-value.aspx

Basically, you need to convert your `mesurementTypes` list/enumerable into a `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

I would recommend, if possible, upgrading to ASP.NET MVC2 and using `Html.DropDownListFor()`

Comment: @alastair i use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in my repository class then why can't i able to set...

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning a SelectionList which can specify a selected item.

[How to create a DropDownList with ASP.NET MVC](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Model.Mes_Id contais the selected value, you can do something like this

```
<%
    var Measurements = new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["MeasurementType"], "Id", "Name", Model.Mes_Id);
    Response.Write(Html.DropDownList("measurement_type", Measurements, "Select"));
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html.DropDownListFor didn't work for me So I got the poppy like this

```
    (in Edit method )

    CreatList(long.Parse(wc.ParentID.ToString()));


    private void CreatList(long selected= 0)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionStringSimple);
        conn.Open();
        Category wn = new Category(conn);
        CategoryCollection coll = new CategoryCollection();
        Category.FetchList(conn, ref coll);

        ViewBag.ParentID = GetList(coll, selected);   
    }


    private List<SelectListItem> GetList(CategoryCollection coll, long selected)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> st = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var cat in coll)
        {
            st.Add( new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = cat.Name,
                Value = cat.ID.ToString(),
                Selected = cat.ID == selected
            });

        }
        SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem { 
                                Text = Resources.lblSelect, 
                                Value = "0" 
        };
        st.Insert(0, s);
        return st;
    }


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlCat", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ParentID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentID)
    </div>
```